# Check if term object is in array

Tags: php, functions, array, terms

I want to check if a term object is in an get_terms array, but i really can't figure out how to do it.

```
$subcat_terms = get_terms([
  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
]);
```

$subcat_terms generates an array like this:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(WP_Term)[10551]
  public 'term_id' => int 16
  public 'name' => string 'Hardware' (length=8)
  public 'slug' => string 'hardware' (length=8)
  public 'term_group' => int 0
  public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 16
  public 'taxonomy' => string 'product_cat' (length=11)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'parent' => int 0
  public 'count' => int 4
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
  public 'meta_value' => string '0' (length=1)
```

I tried to check with the php function in_array, but as it has objects, i don't know how to do this, i would like to check by the term object number or if possible by the term slug. I'll be grateful if someone helps me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress has the `wp_list_pluck` function, which can be helpful here. We can make an array of just term IDs from the array of objects like:

```
$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $subcat_terms, 'term_id' );
```

Then we can check `in_array`:

```
$this_id = 42;
if( in_array( $this_id, $term_ids ) ){ // do something }
```

Comment: Good call on [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/). I always forget about this handy helper function!

Answer (score 1):

A simple `foreach` loop can be used to check if a certain `slug` (or `term_id` or any other property) is in the results returned by `get_terms()`.

In the following example, `$special_term_slugs` holds the slugs we'd like to search for. I used an array here so that we can search for multiple slugs, though it's just fine to use only a single slug.

We get all of the terms for the desired taxonomy, `product_cat`, in this case.

If results are returned, we iterate through them checking to see if the current term object matches one of the slugs defined in our `$special_term_slugs` array.

```
// Array of term slugs to check for. Customize as needed.
$special_term_slugs = [
    'hardware',
];

// Attempt to get the terms.
$subcat_terms = get_terms( [
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
] );

// If we get results, search for our special term slugs.
if ( is_array( $subcat_terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $subcat_terms as $subcat_term ) {
        if ( in_array( $subcat_term->slug, $special_term_slugs ) ) {
             // Special term was found. Do something...

        }
    }
}
```